# Batch loading 2D slices from 3D volumes with Keras Data Generator

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, generator

I have a U-Net based segmentation algorithm in TF/Keras which is trained for 2D segmentation of 3D image volumes (stored as numpy arrays). My 3D image volumes are the same dimensions except for slice number (e.g., 512x512x50, 512x512x200, 512,512,12). Currently the algorithm is loading all of the 3D arrays, concatenating, and then batch loading 512x512 images from the giant 512x512xn(# of total slices) array during training...but this is using up way too much memory.

I would like to use something like `ImageDataGenerator`'s `flow_from_directory` or `flow_from_dataframe` to load arrays as needed during training rather than all at once, but am not sure how to do this since I am dealing with 3D volumes and not directories with 2D images. Is there a type of batch loading available with `ImageDataGenerator` where I can batch load 2D slices from a directory with 3D volumes?

An inefficient workaround would be to open all my 3D arrays and resave as individual slices..but I would prefer to avoid this. Otherwise I guess I could construct a custom generator which uses `numpy.memmap` to load in one slice at a time?

Comment: It sounds like you're treating each slice as its own independent image, correct? If so, stop thinking of them as 3D image volumes. Think of them as collections of 2D images. When you think about it this way, you can see many options: You could manually preprocess the dataset into a set of N independent images, and then treat it just like you would treat a standard large dataset of images. You could make a generator that loads each 3D volume 1 at a time, and then yields a batch as soon as it has enough 2D images. You could simply reduce the size of your dataset so it all fits in memory. Etc.

Comment: Thanks, and yea that's exactly right. Its treated as the equivalent of a bunch of 2d images randomly assembled into 3d arrays and saved as such. I was hoping to avoid rewriting the 3d arrays as individual 2ds. I hadn't considered loading 3d volumes one at a time-I'll give this some thought. Thanks

Comment: Just to elaborate on what I meant by loading one at a time: Say you need batches of 30. You load the first volume, which has 50 slices. You take the first 30 of those and use them as the first batch, and then have 20 left over. For the next batch, you start with those 20 that you already have, then load the next volume. It has 5 slices, so you now have 25. You load the next volume, which has 200 slices. You use the first 5 to finish off the current batch, and then have 195 left over. The next 6 batches can all be taken from those 195, without needing to load any more volumes. Repeat as needed.

Comment: Just note that if the slices within each volume are correlated with one another, then you'll probably want to shuffle the entire dataset, which would mean that this approach is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, and yes each 3d array is associated slices. I was worried about the shuffling aspect of this.. I guess my best move would be to go ahead and rewrite each 3d array as a series of 2ds and then draw from that?

Comment: I was initially envisioning maybe looping through all the 3d arrays with np.memmap and getting slice depth, then building a list (vol1_slice1, vol2_slice2, etc.) of all slices in all 3d arrays, and then batch loading from this list (loading only the appropriate slices rather than full the 3d volumes)

Comment: I'm guessing you are dealing with medical data such as CT. Have you tried to sample 2D slices from 3D volumes? You can build a dataloader that samples say 32 slices from different 3D volumes while keep the ratio between background and foreground 2D slices. If you regard this problem as 2D segmentation, I think maybe it's unnecessarily to load entire 3D volumes at once. One drawback maybe you need heavy post-processing during the inference time.